# package.Json different packages version in the team

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

We are facing different packages version among team members depend on when they run npm i or yarn.
I know the root of the problem is `^` in the version of the package json package list.

Is it goog idea to use the exact version and ignore the minor updates?
Is there a better approach?

thank.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `package-lock.json` file to keep track of the exact version of every package that is installed so that a product is 100% reproducible in the same way even if packages are updated.

`package-lock.json` is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. You need to commit this file in the repostitory after installing/updating a package.

Here are some usefull links to get you started:

[Link1](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-package-lock-json-file)

[Link2](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json)

Comment: I see, but again no guarantee to have the version of the same package until all members run yarn or npm i whenever lock file updated.

Comment: I think so, for the first time all members will need to delete node_modules and do npm i or yarn in order to install packages with exact versions using the lock file. This will be only a one time effort I guess and most packages do not change that often.